# Positioning an element in existing element

Tags: snap.svg

I would like to position a rectangle inside a circle. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df1n3ohj/6/). Unfortunately, the javascript is giving an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null
>       at window.onload

Code is as follows:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var gC=s.select("#green_circle");


gC_cx=gC.attr('cx');
gC_cy=gC.attr('cy');

console.debug(gC_cx);
console.debug(gC_cy);

box=s.rect(gC_cx, gC_cy,100,100);

box.attr({
    fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",
    stroke: "#1f2c39",
    strokeWidth: 3,
    rx: 20,
    ry: 20
});
```

How do i get rid of this error and position the rectangle inside the green circle?

Comment: The error is because you have Snap('#svg'). There is no such id. You either want Snap('svg') or give it an id.

Comment: Changing it to var s = Snap("#layer1"); worked.